# Php Regex - Match an optionnal pattern after any text

Tags: php, regex

I want to match an optionnal specific pattern after a wildcard, how can I achieve this ?

Here is my test string :

```
RGF0027_a_Test string_987.test_004.jpg
```

I want to match the `_004`, it must be optionnal and it can have any text before that.

Here is my current (not working) regex :

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)_(a_)?.*(_(\d+))?\.\w+$
```

Of course the problem is that the `.*` also match the `_004`. I think the answer is to use assertions but I'm not really good with them ...

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5jccg2/2)

Comment: [Change `.*` to `.*?`](https://regex101.com/r/n05wbt/1)

Comment: Oh, it was so simple, thank you !